# Confused with the relationship of the models

Tags: python, django

So I am trying to create the following type of relationship:

Teacher has many students, Student has many Teachers, Student has many(2) Parents, Parent has many Students.

The thing that confuses me is that I am trying to archive that with the extenesion of the AbstractUser. I totally confused myself over how I would create the models. Currently I have this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_parent = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='parents'
    )   

class Parent(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    student = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='students'
    )


class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    student = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='students'
    )
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you're overcomplicating things here. I don't see the need for all those models and one-to-one relations. Why not a simple User model with all the relations?

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    students = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='teachers', symmetrical=False)
    children = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='parents', symmetrical=False)
```

Note, the related name is for the reverse relationship; if you are one of my students, I am your teacher. You don't need separate fields for those. You do need to set symmetrical to False - otherwise Django would assume if you are one of my students, I am one of your students, which is obviously not right.

Comment: You could implement `is_student` properties with queries like `User.teachers.exists()` or so.

Comment: I see.. the reason why I've separated them as different models is that Parent would have different fields than the student. For example, the student would have `'personal_gp_number' ` and the parent wouldn't need that field same applies to the parent and teacher model they would have different fields.